# .htaccess for cdn & staging died

Tags: javascript, html, css, apache, .htaccess

Ok so I'm attempting to use two .htaccess files in order to load content on: http://staging.rjs-creative.com and one on http://cdn.rjs-creative.com in order to display fonts on staging.rjs-creative.com/test.php from cdn.rjs-creative.com/fonts/ - but it doesn't seem to be working and I'm going crazy here!

My ACCESS Log via cdn subdomain shows:

> [14/May/2015:11:10:53 -0400] "GET /fonts/Hoverage-Vintage.otf
>   HTTP/1.0" 200 582 "cdn.rjs-creative.com/css/stylesheet.min.css"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36"

The ERROR Log via staging subdomain shows:

> [Thu May 14 10:26:20 2015] [error] [client 5.189.144.88] Directory
>   index forbidden by Options directive:
>   /var/www/vhosts/rjs-creative.com/httpdocs/

My CDN HTACCESS is as follows..

```
Header unset ETag FileETag None 
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|mp3|mp4)$"> 
    Header set Cache-Control "public" 
    Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2018 20:00:00 GMT" 
    Header set Last-Modified "Thu, 7 Nov 2013 12:00:00 GMT" 
</FilesMatch> 
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|xml|txt|xsl)$"> 
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, must-revalidate" 
</FilesMatch> 
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$"> 
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE 
    Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2018 20:00:00 GMT" 
</FilesMatch> 
AddDefaultCharset utf-8 Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript 
<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on       Yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk  Yes
    mod_gzip_item_include file      \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl|webm)$
    mod_gzip_item_include handler   ^cgi-script$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime      ^text/.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime      ^application/x-javascript.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime      ^image/.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.* 
</IfModule> 
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year" 
</IfModule> 
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Now my STAGING HTACCESS is as follows...

```
<FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff)">  
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" 
</FilesMatch> 
Header unset ETag FileETag None 
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|mp3|mp4)$"> 
    Header set Cache-Control "public" Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2018 20:00:00 GMT" 
    Header set Last-Modified "Thu, 7 Nov 2013 12:00:00 GMT" 
</FilesMatch> 
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|xml|txt|xsl)$"> 
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, must-revalidate" 
</FilesMatch> 
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$"> 
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2018 20:00:00 GMT" 
</FilesMatch> 

AddDefaultCharset utf-8 Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding

<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject   eot
    AddType application/x-font-ttf          .ttf
    AddType font/opentype                   otf
    AddType application/x-font-woff         woff
    AddType image/svg+xml                   svg svgz
    AddEncoding gzip                        svgz 
</Ifmodule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon image/svg+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype 
</Ifmodule>

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on       Yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk  Yes
    mod_gzip_item_include file      \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
    mod_gzip_item_include handler   ^cgi-script$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime      ^text/.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime      ^application/x-javascript.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime      ^image/.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.* 
</IfModule> 
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year" 
</IfModule> 
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Connection keep-alive 
</ifModule> 
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" 
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type" 
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

I am in no way brilliant when it comes to using .htaccess files, but the company that I work for's head developer guided me to use this same .htaccess layout and it seems to work fine when we develop websites there.

I have set my .htaccess to do a 301 redirect which works, to show that the htaccess is definitely initializing. Eugh.